# CSS and JS 404 On Admin Site Only - New Install

Tags: 8, theming, javascript, css-js-aggregation

This is a new server build...

```
me@server:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Apache...

```
me@server:~$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-09-16T12:58:48
```

I downloaded the `Drupal 8.7.8 tar.gz` and installed using the `Standard` installation profile into an Apache `VirtualHost`.  The visitor portion of the site displays and functions as expected, however the admin portion has issues.  The main page, /admin, displays styled.  However, clicking on the various links, Content, Structure, Appearance, etc, result in a page with no style.  Inspect's Network tab shows...

```
http://my.server/admin/sites/default/files/css/css_<snip-long-random-string>.css?0
...
http://my.server/admin/core/assets/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.min.js?v=3.3.1
http://my.server/admin/sites/default/files/js/js_<snip-long-random-string>.js
...
```

Still in Inspect on the Network tab, the CSS files show a Status of "`(cancelled)`" and the JS files are all `404`.

Maybe I have something wrong with URL rewriting.  During installation in the "Requirements review" I received the warning about clean URLs - the server is capable but not enabled.  Well, `mod_rewrite` is enabled and I have the following in my `VirtualHost` config...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With setting `RewriteEngine off` the visitor site only partially works.  For example, the contact form is 404 while search works but has no CSS.

All other prerequisites passed.

I removed the whole Drupal filesystem and dropped the database.  Another new installation yields the same results.  Further suggesting that this is an Apache config issue.

Your time and help in resolving this is appreciated, thank you.

== Edit ==
The more I investigate the more I feel this is `rewrite` related.  I moved all of the Rewrite statements into the top `<Directory>` and the site, visitor and admin, is 100% broken and I now receive the following in Apache's error log...

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
AH00121: r->uri = /index.php
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php
```

The last entry is repeated a number of times.  I have `LogLevel debug`.

I understand the result but I'm not sure what the Rewrite statements should be and where they belong.  My [current] vhost...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [redacted]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
    <Directory /var/www/html/test>
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteOptions inherit
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help.

Comment: Does it fix when you turn off aggregate css and js in `/admin/config/development/performance`?

Comment: @NoSssweat, yes it happens with aggregation on or off.

Comment: I meant .htaccess not vhost conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget `AllowOverride All` if your Apache is defaulted to `AllowOverride None`.  The missing directive was prohibiting rewriting from working [properly?] since I had, lastly, moved the rules to .htaccess (where they are in a default installation).  Added it to the "main" `<Directory>` in my `<VirtualHost>` and all is well.